# General idea how to highlight the selected Parent item in a Menu (using ListView)

Tags: asp.net, listview, menu

So I have a Hierarchical Datasource that contains the information for a menu... I databind it to a ListView and use CSS to format it into a menu.. everything is good.. Now the next step I can't seem to understand..

How do I highlight (set the class of the

) the menu item that was just selected.. They are just links .. Should I somehow identify the ID of what was clicked and then use that to somehow loop through..?

Here is what I got so far so any tips in the right direction are good.

```
 <asp:ListView ID="lvMainOuter" runat="server">
                        <LayoutTemplate>
                            <ul id="menunav" runat="server">
                                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
                            </ul>
                        </LayoutTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <li <%# (Container.DataItem as FigLeafMenuItem).ItemSelected == "true" ? @" class=""MainMenuSelected""" : @" class=""""" %>>
                                <asp:HyperLink ID="nodeLink" runat="server" Text='<%# (Container.DataItem as FigLeafMenuItem).Name %>' NavigateUrl='<%# (Container.DataItem as FigLeafMenuItem).Url %>' />

                                <asp:ListView ID="lvMainInner" DataSource="<%# (Container.DataItem as FigLeafMenuItem).Children %>" runat="server">
                                    <LayoutTemplate>
                                        <ul id="menunav" runat="server">
                                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
                                        </ul>
                                    </LayoutTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <li>
                                            <asp:HyperLink ID="nodeLink" runat="server" Text='<%# (Container.DataItem as FigLeafMenuItem).Name %>' NavigateUrl='<%# (Container.DataItem as FigLeafMenuItem).Url %>' />
                                        </li>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:ListView>
                            </li>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:ListView>
   public int SelectedMenuId { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lvMainOuter.ItemDataBound += lvMainOuter_ItemDataBound;
    lvMainOuter.DataSource = new FigLeafMenu().GetFigLeafTopMenu();
    lvMainOuter.DataBind();

}

void lvMainOuter_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
        //WHAT DO I DO NOW TO GET THE SELECTED ITEM AND ASSIGN IT A CLASS? 
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I am at the point where the inner masterpage/menu needs to render.. but it needs to know the selected ID which the outer masterpage.menu has.. but the inner page renders first before it can know that value.. so how do I get the value ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        <asp:ListView ID="lvMainInner" DataSource="<%# (Container.DataItem as FigLeafMenuItem).Children %>"
        runat="server">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <ul id="menunav" runat="server">
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
            </ul>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="nodeLink" runat="server" Text='<%# (Container.DataItem as FigLeafMenuItem).Name %>'
                    NavigateUrl='<%# (Container.DataItem as FigLeafMenuItem).Url %>' />
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <SelectedItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="nodeLink" CssClass="MyHighlightClass" runat="server" Text='<%# (Container.DataItem as FigLeafMenuItem).Name %>'
                    NavigateUrl='<%# (Container.DataItem as FigLeafMenuItem).Url %>' />
            </li>
        </SelectedItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

or you could use codebehind ...

```
   lvMainInner.SelectedIndexChanged += (o, args) =>
            {
              //You can do whatever here
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

In your hyperlink markup you can set the [CssClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx) to a conditional statement based on some statement right?

Comment: yes.. Just like I have it changing the class to the submenu.. Ok so I can do that. .So I think I got it.. I just have a property called IsSelcted and check that and change the CSS.. But I still need to set a node in the collection to 'IsSelected = true'.. Not sure how I would do that

Comment: Yea that's the trick.  What information do you have to match an item in your collection?  Just the URL?  Or do you have some ID?

Comment: Ok.. I got it.. you get the Url and match it with the Url in the Data source!